# when ever i create a new project in android,after open/load this project,that error is automatically show

Tags: android

when ever i create a new project in android,after open/load this project,that error is automatically show..

this error is show

E:\Tutorial\TabLay2\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: I've seen this occur before because the XML declaration is malformed - take a look at it in your `colours.xml` and make sure it's alright, no superfluous whitespace etc.

Comment: what i have to write in color.xml file

Comment: Take a look at the format of one of your other `.xml` files and compare it to `colours`

Comment: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  E:\Tutorial\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Command: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\fc444429c9ac9f1db8d9bb3790bf9413\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        E:\Tutorial\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        E:\Tutorial\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

Comment: another error is showing